# other class for Dio in flutter

Tags: android-studio, flutter, dio

i'm create a class for dio 
That all my connections to the server happen in this class
Now I want to call onError and onSuccess in other class
An example of this was done in Java with an interface

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have done like this,
First, create a common dio class,

```
class NetworkRepository {
  Future<String> getRequest(String url) async {
    var dio = Dio();
    print(url.toString());
    dio.interceptors.add(InterceptorsWrapper(
        onRequest:(RequestOptions options) async {
          print("REQUEST[${options?.method}] => PATH: ${options?.path}");
          return options; //continue
        },
        onResponse:(Response response) async {
          print("RESPONSE[${response?.statusCode}] => PATH: ${response?.request?.path}");
          return response; // continue
        },
        onError: (DioError err) async {
         print("ERROR[${err.toString()}] => PATH: ${err?.request?.path}");
          return  err;//continue
        }
    ));
    Response response = await dio.get(url);
    print(response.toString());
    return response.toString();
  }
  dynamic requestInterceptor(RequestOptions options) async {
    return options;
  }

}
```

and when you want to call it in your any class,

```
 NetworkRepository().getRequest(projects).then((onValue) {
      var dataConvertedToJSON = json.decode(onValue);
      print(dataConvertedToJSON);
      setState(() {
        ProjectModel model = ProjectModel.fromJson(dataConvertedToJSON);
        mList.add(model);
      });
    });
```

Also you can try [Bloc pattern](https://bloclibrary.dev/#/flutterlogintutorial?id=setup) to do so.